# Подставить значение из переменной

Tags: php, html

`<div id="help"></div>` Необходимо  вставить вместо "help" подставляемое значение из переменной. Решение в лоб  вот такое `<div id=$post></div>`  не работает. Как это сделать?

Comment: <div id="<?php echo $data->id; ?>"> Вон как можно))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так

```
<?php print  "<div id='".$post."'></div>"; ?>
```

или так

```
<?php print  "<div id='$post'></div>";?>
```

или

```
<?php print  "<div id='{$post}'></div>";?>
```

или посреди html(шорт теги должны быть разрешены)

```
<div id='<?=$post?>'></div>
```

**P.s.**
последний способ не пользуется популярностью(как минимум у меня). Вместо него лучше так:

```
<div id='<?php print $post;?>'></div>
```